# Use TLS 1.1 or higher

Tags: eclipse, ide, tls

I am using Force.com IDE-Eclipse Mars and jre7. 
I have added 
`-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` in Eclipse.ini ,but still I am getting this error.I am trying to fetch data from Sandbox.

What am I missing here?

Also,when I am entering wrong password,I am getting error: Invalid username,password,security token or user locked out.

Comment: I have disabled TLS1.0 and enabled TLS1.1 and TLS 1.2 in advanced security settings. and I am using `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` in eclipse.ini.Still,I am getting the same error.Can any one tell what could be the problem

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that TLS 1.0 is successfully deactivated, you can hit this URL in browser and check: https://tls1test.salesforce.com

Also, these are the two steps you need to follow, if TLS1.0 is still active:
To fix this issue in Eclipse -

1) Update your eclipse.ini file to include this line: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 You will find eclipse.ini file in eclipse installation directory.

2) If you are using Java 7, then you need to disable TLS1.0 and enable TLS1.1 and TLS1.2. (GO to control panel --> Java --> Advanced --> Advanced Security settings). TLS 1.0 is disabled by default in Java 8.

Comment: More details: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221207

Comment: Hey Deepish,I have disabled TLS1.0 and enabled TLS1.1 and TLS 1.2 in advanced security settings. and  I was already using `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` in eclipse.ini.Still,I am getting the same error.

Comment: What is the result when you hit the URL in browser: https://tls1test.salesforce.com ?

Comment: TLS 1.0 Deactivation Test Passed

Comment: Do you have another salesforce org to try out?
Seems like TLS is not the problem here, but the credentials is.

Comment: I tried with my own developer sandbox and It is working.But it is no working with other sandbox and If I am providing incorrect credentials, then I am getting error: Invalid username,password,security token or user locked out. Otherwise it is showing TLS1.1 error

Comment: But again,that was a production sandbox which still allows TLS1.0

Answer (score 0):

After adding -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 it is working for me. please check the java version it should be grater than 1.7